# WordPress i want custom link in user list when i click the link get the images by user

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add link in user list by adding this code

```
function frontend_profile_action_link($actions, $user_object) {
    $actions['view profile'] = "<a class='view_frontend_profile' href='".admin_url().'user-detail.php'."'>".__('View Profile', 'frontend_profile')."</a>";
    return $actions;
}
add_filter('user_row_actions', 'frontend_profile_action_link', 10, 2);
```

I want to add custom link in user list like default edit link and then when I click this link get all images by user

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tackle

```
<?php $user = get_user_by( $field, $value ); ?>
```

or if you specified a custom field in the registration form you can use

```
<?php get_userdata( $field ); ?>
```

Comment: i dont use custom field.

Comment: custom link in  back admin user list

Comment: In the admin panel? You might try for a plugin I'm sure there should be plenty of them for admin panel customizations.